# When to use ObservableCollection vs AdvisableCollection w/ PostSharp NotifyPropertyChanged?

Tags: c#, containers, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged, postsharp

**Here is the PostSharp [support discussion](http://support.sharpcrafters.com/discussions/problems/2875-notifypropertychanged-and-observablecollection) (titled: "NotifyPropertyChanged and ObservableCollection") that sparked my initial confusion on this topic.  Further explanation is in the answer I posted (not 100% confident in my answer).**

I'm a little confused on how PostSharp's `[NotifyPropertyChanged]` aspect affects a class's collection properties (if at all), and whether I need to be using an `ObservableCollection<>` or `AdvisableCollection<>`.  If I understand correctly, if I want notifications from the collection, I MUST change it to at least an `ObservableCollection<>`, correct?  The `[NotifyPropertyChanged]` aspect doesn't magically make whatever collection types are in the class observable.

If that's the case, then when would I use `ObservableCollection<>` or `AdvisableCollection<>`?  Should `AdvisableCollection<>` be reserved for when I need the aggregation pattern applied by PostSharp?  Or should I just always use `AdvisableCollection<>` whenever applying PostSharp's `[NotifyPropertyChanged]` attribute?

```
[NotifyPropertyChanged]
public class Test {
    public int PropVal { get; set; }
    public List<string> PropCollection { get; set; } //Should this be ObservableCollection
                                                    //or AdvisableCollection?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congratulations on the Tumbleweed badge and many apologies for the delayed answer.

Collections are currently not well integrated with the aspect in sense that there is a bit of work needed for real-life examples to work properly. Let me explain few key steps:

`[AggregateAllChanges]` instructs the runtime that it should relay any change observed on the collection as a change of the property itself. This in particular means that a virtual `Item[]` dependency is created (which is used by a "standard" collections to notify change of collection shallow "state").

In reality properties working with collections content are usually aggregates in some sense, depending not only on set of items stored in the collection but also on state of individual objects in the collection. Currently there is no way to express that and/or selectively relay these changes. For this you need to create a class derived from `ObservableCollection<T>` that looks like following:

```
[NotifyPropertyChanged]
public class ObservableCollectionEx<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
        {
            foreach (T item in e.OldItems)
            {
                ((INotifyPropertyChanged)item).PropertyChanged -= OnItemPropertyChanged;
            }
        }
        else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            foreach (T item in e.NewItems)
            {
                ((INotifyPropertyChanged)item).PropertyChanged += OnItemPropertyChanged;
            }
        }

        base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected void OnItemPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        NotifyPropertyChangedServices.SignalPropertyChanged(this, "Item[]");

        NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs collectionChangedEventArgs = new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset);
        base.OnCollectionChanged(collectionChangedEventArgs);
    }
}
```

The above does exactly what is needed - when anything changes on any object within the collection, collection reports that it itself had changed.

Now in a class it would look like this:

```
[NotifyPropertyChanged]
public class TestClass
{
    [AggregateAllChanges]
    public ObservableCollectionEx<TestItem> Items { get; } = new ObservableCollectionEx<TestItem>();

    [SafeForDependencyAnalysis]
    public int Sum
    {
        get
        {
            if (Depends.Guard)
            {
                Depends.On(this.Items);
            }

            return this.Items.Sum(x => x.Value);
        }
    }
}

[NotifyPropertyChanged]
public class TestItem
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

The above is not ideal performance-wise if there are other properties on the `TestItem` class that are frequently changed. In that case, one may consider to add a some kind of filtering to `ObservableCollectionEx`.

Regarding `AdvisableCollection<T>` you are right - while it can be used, it's main purpose is different.

Comment: Thanks very much for the response, that helps.  And no apology needed, I was merely amused by the Tumbleweed badge, which I had not seen until this point :), and it was quite helpful for me to have to dig through those docs and discussions anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Well, after receiving the "Tumbleweed" badge on this question (not intended, but funny... better than downvotes), I've spent some more time trying to sort out/better define my confusion and coalesce my own answer from the chaos...

The PostSharp [support discussion](http://support.sharpcrafters.com/discussions/problems/2875-notifypropertychanged-and-observablecollection) (titled: "NotifyPropertyChanged and ObservableCollection") that sparked my initial confusion mentions two things:

-Support for intercepting changes in `ObservableCollection<>` was added in 4.2.

-To raise the `PropertyChanged` event on each collection change, the collection must be marked with `[AggregateAllChanges]`.

So it would seem PostSharp's `NotifyPropertyChanged` aspect supports at least `ObservableCollection<>` if the `[AggregateAllChanges]` attribute is applied.  However, a subsequent conversation on the PostSharp site's chat feature yielded:

-"You need to use collection classes defined by PostSharp to have reliable support for `NotifyPropertyChanged` aspect.  See [Working With Collections](http://doc.postsharp.net/advisable-collections)" (which mentions the Aggregatable pattern).

-After reading the provided documentation, the conclusion seems to be that I need to use `AdvisableCollection<>` (a PostSharp-defined collection) instead, but the examples all seem to be in the context of the Aggregatable pattern, with parent-child relationships, etc.  Hence my confusion.  I'm not trying to set up parent-child relationships, just trying to get `NotifyPropertyChange` on collections.

Next is another [support discussion](http://support.sharpcrafters.com/discussions/questions/1414-bindinglist-and-aggregateallchanges) that demonstrates using `NotifyPropertyChanged` with a non-PostSharp-defined collection, applying `[AggregateAllChanges]` to a `BindingList<>`.

-In this instance, `BindingList<>` did not have one of the events that `NotifyPropertyChanged` expected, so this had to be wired up manually with `NotifyPropertyChangedServices`.

For a bit more background, I read this [PostSharp blog post](http://www.postsharp.net/blog/post/New-in-PostSharp-32-Aggregation-and-Composition-Patterns) that gets into the Aggregation and Composition patterns.

**Trying to boil everything down, my (possibly incorrect) conclusion is:**

**-`[AggregateAllChanges]` applied to non-PostSharp-defined collections (`ObservableCollection<>`, `BindingList<>`) is effectively an opt-in to the `NotifyPropertyChanged` aspect, with the caveat that the collection you apply it to (ex. `BindingList<>`) may not support all of the events the aspect expects, requiring you to wire up the PropertyChanged notification yourself via `NotifyPropertyChangedServices`.**

**-`AdvisableCollection<>` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` as well as `INotifyCollectionChanged` (as does `ObservableCollection<>`), can be used in place of standard .net collections (not `BindingList<>` though... different interfaces), and would still require `[AggregateAllChanges]` to raise PropertyChanged notifications.  Otherwise, the purpose of `AdvisableCollection<>` is to allow injection of behaviors related to the Aggregatable pattern.**

If anyone has corrections to these assumptions, please feel free :)  I will gladly mark a clearer/better explanation as the answer.